# Compare Hashtable and IDictionary for the same data (asp.net, c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, compare, hashtable

I am currently having a problem trying to compare a Hashtable and a Dictionary agaisnt each other.

I am using a Telerik radgrid to do an update.

On the update i want to check if the oldvalues are exactly the same as the new values, if they match i will just cancel out of the method.

Below is the code I am using. I store newvalues in a Hashtable and SavedOldValues in a IDictionary.

```
    if ((e.Item is GridEditableItem) && e.Item.IsInEditMode && e.CommandName.Equals("Update"))
    {
        try
        {
            GridEditableItem UpdateItem = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;
            Hashtable newValues = new Hashtable();
            e.Item.OwnerTableView.ExtractValuesFromItem(newValues, UpdateItem);
            IDictionary oldValues = UpdateItem.SavedOldValues;
```

Update to question:
So i have took advice below and loop though the oldValues Dictionary and check if the key exists in the newValues Hashtable.

Below is what I am looking to achieve. Basically i need to use the key to find the value in the dictionary however i cannot seem to get it to work.

Error i get is object does not contain a definition for Contains

```
    foreach (DictionaryEntry oldEntry in oldValues)
                {
                    if (newValues.ContainsKey(oldEntry.Key) && 
                        newValues[oldEntry.Key].Contains(oldEntry.Value))
                    {
                       //Data matches 
                    }
                }
```

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: `HashTable` is a completely obsolete data structure, and has been for over a decade.  You should really avoid using it entirely, and just use a `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

Since dictionary that you are using is not generic, then retrieval of values from `IDictionary` and `Hashtable` takes the same time. But hashtable adds thread safety.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is you need to **sort** your retrieved data, from both collections, into the same format. That way these new sorted collections can be assumed to be in the same order, and therefore if they are equivalent, you will have the same values.

You can populate some nice classes like [SortedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx) that are already accessible by your code, or write your own sorting algorithm. Then just compare the two sorted collection by each element to check for equivalence.

Additionally you could loop through the HashTaple or Dictionary and call `ContainsKey(TKey)` and `ContainsValue(TValue)` on the non-looped-through collection to check for equivalence.